# How do I programmatically add a click event to an existing text link after saving an object in Angular?

Tags: angular

First of all I am new at Angular so bear with me.

I'm trying to add a click event function to an existing text link after a sale is saved and it passes into the function the Id.  Please see example below.

```
                 :
                <wizard-step [title]="l('StepSubmitSale')" 
                 [showPrev]="!isCompleted" (onComplete)="onComplete($event)">
                  <div [ngSwitch]="isCompleted">
                    <div *ngSwitchDefault>
                      <!-- <h1>Step4</h1> -->
                      <div>Sale Summary Step</div>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngSwitchCase="true">
                      <div>Sale Completed</div>
                       <button #mybtn>Print Documents</button>
                      <div><a href="javascript:;" (click)="createSale()">Add 
                       Another Sale</a></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </wizard-step>
              </form-wizard>


@ViewChild('mybtn') myBtn: ElementRef;

save(): void {
    this.saving = true;
        this._saleServiceProxy.createOrEdit(this.sale)
         .pipe(finalize(() => { this.saving = false;}))
         .subscribe(result => {
            this.notify.info(this.l('SavedSuccessfully'));
            this.isCompleted = true;
            alert('Result ' + result.id);              
            let btn = this.myBtn.nativeElement.querySelector('#mybtn');
            alert('Button' + btn);
            btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => { this.downloadNewFile(result.id) });               
            this.modalSave.emit(null);
         });
}
```

However, it's not working. The btn object does not pick up when alert is called.  Actually, no alert is shown for the btn.

Now I have already looked on the internet trying to use Renderer with no luck and with the example above.

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: There are 3 different ways I'm vaguely understanding this, can you be mosre specific about exactly what you want to occur?  From the way you're asking it kind of sounds like you want to edit your HTML, which would have one answer.  But then this could be your way of asking how to make something extra happen through an existing click event, which would have another answer.  Or once I know for sure what you want to do, there may be a different approach that needs to be taken to allow that flexibility.  What's the step by step funcitonality you want to occur?

Comment: also I see there's both a `<button> and an `<a>` tag present.  The `<a>` tag has a click event, so that leaves 2 possible starting points for whatever process you want to occur.  Being so consumed by it yourself can make things appear to be a lot clearer than what they really are to others who haven't been racking their brain over it for a couple days lol.

Answer (score 0):

View child already returns you the element reference. When you ask .querySelector('#mybtn') you're actually looking for element with id="mybtn" in your `<button>` element

Use renderer2 instead of calling addEventListener directly.
Accessing nativeElement directly is discouraged by Angular

[here the doc](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef)

```
save(): void {
  this.saving = true;
      this._saleServiceProxy.createOrEdit(this.sale)
       .pipe(finalize(() => { this.saving = false;}))
       .subscribe(result => {
          this.notify.info(this.l('SavedSuccessfully'));
          this.isCompleted = true;
          alert('Result ' + result.id);
          this.myBtn.nativeElement.addEventListener('click', (event) => { this.downloadNewFile(result.id) });
          this.modalSave.emit(null);
       });
}
```

Comment: The doc provided doesn't any example how to use Renderer2.  Can you provide an example that will fit with my issue?

Comment: Thanks Steve.  Your example works but when I implement into my code it doesn't work.  It may be because the button is in a wizard step.  How do I find any html element in a wizard step?

Comment: Hard to say. If you provide me with more code I may help)

Comment: I have added in more code in the original post to show the part of the wizard.  I hope that's enough for you to help me out.

Comment: I see. After assigning `this.isComplete = true` you need to let angular perfom change detection and only after the button is drawn in template add listener to it. You can do that by using setTimeout. Here link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5khwbo . Also make sure your set`{static: false}` on ViewChild as your button has some condition to be drawn